# How to replace character accented characters in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to replace accented characters from a column to "normal" characters.

```sql
select 'áááããã'
```

I'd like some operation which would return 'aaaaaa'.

Comment: Basically you are asking here to convert between utf8 to ascii ?

Answer (score 3):

Just found a solution with one of my colleagues.

```sql
select translate('áááããã','áéíóúãõâêôàç','aeiouaoaeoac')
```

We can also add a `lower()` to make it generalized for more cases

```sql
select translate(lower('ÁÁÁÃÃÃ'),'áéíóúãõâêôàç','aeiouaoaeoac')
```

Comment: Be very sure to test it with different [Collation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/collation.html) as the manual about [translate](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/translate.html) mentioned 
*"Collation Details Arguments with collation specifications are currently not supported.
"*

Answer (score 2):

There is a more general way that uses a built-in JavaScript function to replace them:

[Remove Diacritics from string in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031822/remove-diacritics-from-string-in-snowflake)

```
create or replace function REPLACE_DIACRITICS("str" string)
returns string
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$
    return str.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "");
$$;

select REPLACE_DIACRITICS('ö, é, č => a, o e, c');
```