# Snowflake - Diacritics - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I use the following command line in a JAVASCRIPT UDF function in SNOWFLAKE to remove accents from a text string.

```
const str = "Crème Brulée"
str.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
```

But when I try this command line it doesn't work. It's supposed to work with the new version of Javascript ({Diacritic})

```
const str = "Crème Brulée"
str.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
```

Error showing

> SQL Error [100131] [P0000]: JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught
> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /p{Diacritic}/:

What could cause the problem? to the snowflake JavaScript version that did not yet work with this new functionality?

I am trying with this command line which was taken from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript).

```
const str = "Crème Brulée"
str.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format. Don't add tags. Also use the tools available to you in the editor to format your code properly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031822/remove-diacritics-from-string-in-snowflake